# In SQL, is there something similar to countif statement or a way to show grouped results as columns instead of rows?

Tags: sql, azure

Is there a way to apply a filter to a distinct count using SQL, similar using the `countif` statement in Excel? Or maybe a way of using the `Group By` statement but list each unique group as columns instead of rows.

The database I am querying looks something like this:

| Name | Case # | Case Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joey | 123 | Quote |
| Joey | 124 | Endorsement |
| Joey | 125 | Endorsement |
| Joey | 126 | Endorsement |
| Sarah | 127 | Quote |
| Sarah | 128 | Phone Call |
| Sarah | 129 | Endorsement |

What I want to do is end up with something like this:

| Name | Endorsement | Quote | Phone Call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joey | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| Sarah | 1 | 1 | 1 |

My current code:

```
Select Case_Owner_Name__c,Case_Queue__c As Case_Queue, 
  Count(Distinct CaseNumber) As Case_Count 
from slss.case
Group By Case_Owner_Name__c,Case_Queue__c;
```

Is there a way to filter the `Count(Distinct CaseNumber)` so that it only counts the `Case #` if it matches a certain `Case Type`?

Comment: Probably using SQL Server.

Comment: yes it is called pivot search for it with the rdms name

Answer (score 1):

You can use traditional *conditional aggregation* to pivot. For example:

```
select
  name,
  sum(case when case_type = 'Endorsement' then 1 else 0 end) as endorsement,
  sum(case when case_type = 'Quote' then 1 else 0 end) as quote,
  sum(case when case_type = 'Phone Call' then 1 else 0 end) as phone_call
from case
group by name
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this same result but only if the case number is unique? I found that there are alot of duplicate cases in the database so I don't want to include those.